# A rot has set into this Crossword!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-crosswords

[image]

The Clues:

**Across**

2: Tungsten for Hundred in tilt gives Chinese frying Pan (16,0)
5: Copied a monkey beginning to dance(5,0)
7: Adjusted tailless fish with Sheeran(7,4)
9: Rage boils over for equipment(4,0)
10: Burn a letter,maybe?(13,0)
13: Lebanon's Leader in amount for German River(14,0)
14: Prey destroyed in fire(10,0)
16: That is in against of fights(9,3)
17: Quinton, Una initially with tech field resigned(18,3)

**Down**

1: Short Electrical Engineering in full service, shortly for Payment(9,3)
2: Which first winner's helmet? (7,0)
3: Notebook-Shortly for Underage Italian city (11,0)
4: Beastly, Emrakul at first with Rand Al', Nathanel at last to start fight(9,1)
6: Endless joy with Joe gives yoga guy(12,2)
8: The French in Chlorine gives membrane (6,3)
11: Hungary's chief's anger gives employment (22,3)
12: Russia's head with us and Kiev's chief for biscuit (20,0)
15: I with Extra terrestrial for event(22,2)

Comment: @Moehm I am sorry I made a mistake. I will try to rectify soon.

Comment: The down clue numbers don't match the crossword grid (for example, there is no 7 down).  Is that intentional?

Comment: @MikeQ If that's the only apparent inconsistency you've noticed in this puzzle, you need to look further ;-)

Comment: @Mike Fixed stuff.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list of clue answers is:

> Across: `(c->W)OCK`, `APE+D`, `TUN(-a)+ED`, `GEAR*`, `CHAR (ddef)`, `SU(L)M`, `PYRE*`, `V(IE)S`, `Q_+U_+IT`
>  Down: `F_ (E_E_) S_`, `W_+HAT`, `PAD+UA`, `B_ + E_ + _L + _L`, `JO(-y)+GI`, `C(AU)L`, `H+IRE`, `R_+US+K_`,`ME+ET`

And the numbers can be interpreted by

> Caesar ciphering each clue by the first number, then "rotating" by the second (moving that many letters from the front to the back). This makes a list of cities: MESA, FUJI, KABUL, KIEV, PUNE, GIZA, ZIBO, BERN, LIMA, BONN, DOHA, AFOLI, NUUK, SUVA, RIGA, ADEN, LOME, APIA.

As Sid confirmed in chat, there is nothing more to the puzzle.

A full list of clue explanations (provided by Sp3000, who did the majority of the work for this puzzle) is on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13TcONgM0WMPED_oDhbF8OPO0_oJZXnytdiy3V2KYO2c/edit#gid=0).

Comment: How do you get AU for "French in"

Comment: Never mind.  I missed the edit where "The" was added.

Answer (score 7):

Partial -- I haven't given thought to the ROT part, nor have I looked at the parentheticals.  But here are some of the cryptics.

Across

2: Tungsten for Hundred in tilt gives Chinese frying Pan (16,0)

> WOCK --  Tungsten for Hundred p means 'Replace C (100) with W (Tungsten)' in a word meaning Tilt (COCK).  Apparently WOCK is an alternative spelling for WOK, a chinese frying pan.

5: Copied a monkey beginning to dance(5,0)

> APED (double def on Copy, monkey, + d from dance)

7: Adjusted tailless fish with Sheeran(7,4)

> TUN + ED (Tailless TUNA, + ED)

9: Rage boils over for equipment(4,0)

> GEAR - (anagram of rage)

10: Burn a letter,maybe?(13,0)

> CHAR (double def)

13: Lebanon's Leader in amount for German River(14,0)

> SU(L)M

14: Prey destroyed in fire(10,0)

> PYRE (anagram)

16: That is in against of fights(9,3)

> V(IE)S

17: Quinton, Una initially with tech field resigned(18,3)

> Q + U + IT (initials, + IT (information Tech)

Down

1: Short Electrical Engineering in full service, shortly for Payment(19,3)

> F(EE)S

2: Which first winner's helmet? (7,0)

> W + HAT

3: Notebook-Shortly for Underage Italian city (10,0)

> PAD + UA

4: Beastly, Emrakul at first with Rand Al', Nathanel at last to start fight(9,1)

6: Endless joy with Joe gives yoga guy(12,2)

> JO + GI (Apparently, that's a word)

8: French in Chlorine gives membrane (6,3)

11: Hungary's chief's anger gives employment (22,3)

> H + IRE

12: Russia's head with us and Kiev's chief for biscuits (20,0)

> R + US (lit) + K - RUSK (error in clue. "biscuits" should be "biscuit"

15: I with Extra terrestrial for event(22,2)

> ME + ET (as in a track meet)

Comment: 2A,6D and 13A are wrong. Do see that 13A is 4 letters and not 5 letters. For 2A, You have the right idea but the spelling is an alternate version of it.

Comment: Now, correct. 2A is probably a tad unfair given I saw the word in only one website. But, you have the right idea. Tilt has another meaning. You will get it then.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too happy about that one.  Tried the alternative spelling, and got a hit.

Comment: Figured out  11 Down